# ExtJS - Grid filter with multiple columns and multiple values

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, multiple-columns, multiple-value

I create a grid and a toolbar with Two Menu of menuCheckItem. When i check the menuCheckItem the grid filters even with multiple values and multiple columns.
This working fine, as I have created grid 1st and then the toolbar

```
this.up('') // Used Instead of Ext.getCmp()
```

Working FIDDLE - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lop

Now I am trying to create same toolbar along with Menu separately on top 1st and then create grid at below. But while doing this, nly Multiple values is working.

I am trying to filter grid with multiple values as well as multiple columns.

Few things i tried -

```
// Only Filters One Value at a time with each Columns
store.queryBy(function(record,id){
 return (record.get('name') == someValue && record.get('phone') == otherValue);
});
```

and

```
// Filters Many Columns with Single Value
filter.add(
     property : name, phone
     value : "somevalue"
     operator : "OR"
```

);

Is there any way to implement Toolbar 1st and then grid ? And Filter grid with many values and columns simultaneously ?

Comment: So your problem is that you can't filter grid with both checkbox menus? Bcz if i filter by number and then by name, number filter is removed and only name filter remains. Did i get right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.@beso9595. The Fiddle which i have give works fine, even if i filter by number and then by name,Both the name and phoneNo. filter is applied. Bcuz I create grid 1st and then toolbar menu, so by using ".up()" i am able to achieve both filters.  But if i create toolbar and grid as separate elements, I couldn't sync both name and phoneNo filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lp2) i remade a function(`checkchange`), which is universal , can be put separately and you'll be able to attach it to every `menucheckitem` you create. The only thing is that if you add new menucheckitem filter you should name the menucheckitem `id` with the name of the `columnDataIndex-Menu` and add this `columnDataIndex` in `menuFilters` and thats all.

```
checkchange: function (checkbox, checked, eOpts) {
    var menuFilters = ['name', 'phone'];
    var getChecked = function (m) {
        var checkedItems = [];
        m.items.items.forEach(function (c) {
            if (c.checked) {
                checkedItems.push(c.text);
            }
        });
        return checkedItems;
    };
    //
    var menus = new Map();
    menuFilters.forEach(function (e) {
        menus.set(e, Ext.getCmp(e + '-Menu'));
    });
    //
    var fieldValues = [];
    menuFilters.forEach(function (e) {
        fieldValues.push([e, getChecked(menus.get(e))]);
    });
    //
    var store = checkbox.up('grid').store;
    store.clearFilter();
    //
    if (fieldValues.length > 0) {
        store.filterBy(function (record) {
            var fV = this.fieldValues;
            for (var i = 0; i < fV.length; i++) {
                if (fV[i][1].length > 0) {
                    if (fV[i][1].indexOf(record.get(fV[i][0])) === -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }, {
            fieldValues: fieldValues
        });
    }
}
```